# Using subscriber to subscribe the Lidar's signal Topic

Tags: ros, laserscanner, topic, scan

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello ROS users,
I am using a subscriber to subscribe lidar's signal. I have watched the subscriber and publisher example(C++) tutorial's video and use catkin_ws to build a package, and I make a sick_listen roscpp file which the coding is copied from the listener in the tutorial. And I modify the coding for using it to subscribe the my lidar's signal topic. The coding as below is what I modified and my spec of my ROS

```
include "ros/ros.h"

include "std_msgs/String.h"

void laser_msg_Callback(const std_msgs::String::ConstPtr& msg)
{
  ROS_INFO("I heard: [%s]", msg->data.c_str());
}                  

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

  ros::init(argc, argv, "sick_listener"); 

  ros::NodeHandle n;

  ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe("scan", 811, laser_msg_Callback);

  ros::spin();

  return 0;

}
```

Spec: ubuntu 14.04LTS, Jade ROS, sick tim 561 lidar

And These are the message type of the "lidar's topic" and "talker's topic which is from the tutorial" comparison:

```
 1. terry@terry-All-Series:~$ rostopic type  /chatter std_msgs/String
 2. terry@terry-All-Series:~$ rostopic type  /scan sensor_msgs/LaserScan
```

When I run the code of sick_listen, it shows the error as below:

```
[ INFO] [1451458683.021191460]: Waiting 50 seconds for device to connect.
[ INFO] [1451458683.021602292]: Succesfully connected to 192.168.1.144:2111
[ERROR] [1451458683.224815412]: Client [/sick_listener] wants topic /scan to have datatype/md5sum [std_msgs/String/992ce8a1687cec8c8bd883ec73ca41d1], but our version has [sensor_msgs/LaserScan/90c7ef2dc6895d81024acba2ac42f369]. Dropping connection.
```

I am a niewbe in the ROS and not to familiar to the c code,so do I need to use the other header of the code for the lidar?
I would be thankful if someone can give me some direction.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/223252/using-subscriber-to-subscribe-the-lidar%27s-signal-topic/) by [Terry Su](https://answers.ros.org/users/25230/terry-su/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2015-12-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As the error tells, your message types are inconsistent.
Try the correct message type which is `sensor_msgs::LaserScan` instead of `std_msgs::String`.

```
void laser_msg_Callback(const sensor_msgs::LaserScan::ConstPtr& scan)
{
  //you can get readings with scan->ranges[]
}
```

And also of course you should add `#include "sensor_msgs/LaserScan.h"`.

---

Originally posted by [Akif](https://answers.ros.org/users/23527/akif/) with karma: 3561 on 2015-12-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Terry Su](https://answers.ros.org/users/25230/terry-su/) on 2015-12-30**:
Hello Akif, when I follow your advice to add the header and "scan->ranges[]", it has an error as:
expected primary-expression before ‘]’ token
ROS_INFO("I heard: [%s]", scan->ranges[]);

**Comment by [Akif](https://answers.ros.org/users/23527/akif/) on 2015-12-30**:
@Terry Su, You should also write your index of data. Like `scan->ranges[0]`, `scan->ranges[1]` etc. , whichever reading you want to get.

**Comment by [Terry Su](https://answers.ros.org/users/25230/terry-su/) on 2015-12-30**:
@Akif, It is really works! Thank you so much! Could you please tell me that the index meaning in the braket of "range[]", I search it after you told me to input the index, but nothing. Finally, thank you.

**Comment by [Akif](https://answers.ros.org/users/23527/akif/) on 2015-12-30**:
index will depend on the sensor. For example, if it is measuring 180 deg. with 1 deg. resolution, then your `ranges` array size will be probably 181, i.e., each range measurement depending on the angle. You can check the size of `ranges`. Also, if your problem solved please mark answer as correct.

**Comment by [Terry Su](https://answers.ros.org/users/25230/terry-su/) on 2015-12-30**:
@Akif, My lidar's scan range is 270 deg with 0.333 deg resolution, so the index what I need is ranges[811] because 270/0.33=811,its right? And the subscriber's receive data what terminal shows is like:

- [ INFO] [1451481162.429434168]: I heard: [P?j]
- [ INFO] [1451481162.429434168]: I heard:[?]

**Comment by [Terry Su](https://answers.ros.org/users/25230/terry-su/) on 2015-12-30**:
Is this because the value is array, so that shows up the strange value as "[P?j]", "[?]" or something like that?

**Comment by [Akif](https://answers.ros.org/users/23527/akif/) on 2015-12-30**:
Are you printing with `%s`? I think you should try `%f` for float.

**Comment by [Terry Su](https://answers.ros.org/users/25230/terry-su/) on 2015-12-30**:
@ Akif, Yes! Thank you so much. But when I change the index to range[811], it just show 1 value of distance. But when I use the "rostopic echo /scan", it shows 811 values. I also search the "range[]" in the website and ROS, but just see the laser msg type.

**Comment by [Akif](https://answers.ros.org/users/23527/akif/) on 2015-12-30**:
@Terry Su, all of your scan readings are stored in `ranges` array. You can loop through it and do whatever you want. Like, `for (int x=0;x< scan->ranges.size();x++){ ROS_INFO("Scan %d: %f", x, scan->ranges[x]); }`

**Comment by [Terry Su](https://answers.ros.org/users/25230/terry-su/) on 2015-12-30**:
@Akif, So when the index is ranges[811], there are 811 values store in the ranges? And when I put you code in my file, it shows the:

1. error: expected initializer before ‘for’
2. error: ‘x’ does not name a type

**Comment by [Terry Su](https://answers.ros.org/users/25230/terry-su/) on 2015-12-30**:
After that, I put the #include "String.h" in my header, but it still has same error. Sorry that I not familiar about c code. Thank you for your kindly help.

**Comment by [Akif](https://answers.ros.org/users/23527/akif/) on 2015-12-30**:
@Terry Su, if you have 811 readings, ranges can have index maximum of 810 since it starts from 0. For the error, I need to see your whole code at that point. Can you share it somewhere?

**Comment by [Terry Su](https://answers.ros.org/users/25230/terry-su/) on 2016-01-01**:
@Akif, This is the coding of mine which I follow your example in the void laser part:
`void laser_msg_Callback(const sensor_msgs::LaserScan::ConstPtr& scan) for (int x=0;x< scan->ranges.size();x++) { ROS_INFO("Scan %d: %f", x, scan->ranges[x]);); }` Thank you for your kindly help.

**Comment by [Akif](https://answers.ros.org/users/23527/akif/) on 2016-01-01**:
@Terry Su, you are missing brakets for the callback function and you have extra paranthesis after ROS_INFO. Maybe you should check some C/C++ tutorials. [This code should work](http://pastebin.com/fnYVS9vs).

**Comment by [Terry Su](https://answers.ros.org/users/25230/terry-su/) on 2016-01-01**:
@Akif, Thank you for your kindly help really!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

you need to import the definition for the type of message you are receiving, and create a callback that takes that format of message (LaserScan rather than String)

---

Originally posted by [nickw](https://answers.ros.org/users/4160/nickw/) with karma: 1504 on 2015-12-30

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1